# MVC 3 Authorize List of Users Pulled Dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

I am using Windows Authentication. I am restricting access at the controllers by using this:

```
[Authorize(Users = @"MYDOMAIN\BillB, MYDOMAIN\MaryH, MYDOMAIN\BobN")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
  //stuff
}
```

But I want to grab this list dynamically from a database. Something like:

```
[Authorize(Users = MyListOfAuthorizedUsers)]
```

I tried just making the list manually like this to test the concept:

```
List<string> MyListOfAuthorizedUsers = new List<string>()
    {
        "MYDOMAIN\BillB",
        "MYDOMAIN\\MaryH",
        "MYDOMAIN\\BobN"
    };
```

Doesn't work of course... but is there a way like this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add those users to a an AD group and then authorize by group?

Comment: I know but - then we are dependent on AD administrators to enable new admins for the app. This way the application administrators have complete control. If they add a new administrator, it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create your own authorize attribute by extending `AuthorizeAttribute` so that you can perform custom authorization including pulling in the list of users or any other logic you need.

[This](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes) link shows you an example of how it would look like. Half way down is the `AuthorizeCore` method which is what you need to override.

Comment: That helped. I got it working - kind of. Where do I make this class so that I can just call it [MyCustomAuthorize] - Like what namespace is it in? [Sry for the vague understanding on my part.]

Comment: You can add this under any namespace and just add a using statement to classes that need it. Something like an AppName.Common namespace that all classes reference works best.

Comment: Here is what I did  - please tell me if this is a dumb way to do it... I made a new folder in the solution and named it Common. I created a new class in that folder called AdminAuthorize that inherits from the AuthorizeAttribute class. I override the AuthorizeCore method. It seems to work fine. I put a Using statement in the classes that need it. And I am able to reference it by decorating with [AdminAuthorize].